# Is this curve closed?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

[image: Curve]

Is this curve closed? It seems like if you follow the black line closest to the point $z$, you return to the same point, without every touching the outermost part of the "curve". So I'm wondering if this is even a curve at all as it appears you need to "jump" to get to the centre part of the curve.

Comment: In the context of topology usually one requires a "curve" to be the image of a continuous map $I \to X$, where $I \subset \Bbb R$ is an interval (and in particular $I$ is connected). In particular, any "curve" in this sense is connected.

Comment: @TravisWillse So by that definition, the black line(s) would not be a curve, correct?

Comment: Correct: https://i.imgur.com/ZrCsQv8.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a pair of curves, and one lies inside the other. $z$ is inside the inner curve.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$z$ is situated in the interior of a single curve iff any ray (half-line) issued from $z$ has an *odd number of intersections* with the curve$^*$.

This is not the case here (we always have an even number of intersection points). Thus we aren't in the case of a simple contour.

$^*$**Remarks** :

1) Of course, counting intersection points either we avoid tangent cases or count them as a double intersection.

2) See for example a "concrete" application [here](https://www.mdpi.com/1996-1944/12/23/3835/htm) (see Fig. 5).